# Rspec seems to be passing portion of test that should be failing [Rails 4 In Action]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working through Rails 4 In Action by Bigg, Katz, and Klabnik and for me personally, it's my first introduction to the rspec testing platform.

I'm encountering a situation where the expected Failure reason as noted in the text does *NOT* coincide with the Failure message I am receiving. In fact, my Failure seems to be happening at a later line, which makes me think rspec is passing a portion that should be failing.

The issue the text is expecting the test to reject is Failure/Error: click_link "New Ticket" / NoMethodError: / undefined method 'tickets' for yadda yadda.  Which makes complete sense since I have NOT yet coded this method into the tickets controller.

Instead I'm receiving an error related to a missing "Title" field and a missing "Create Ticket" button, which as shown in the code below, is after rspec tests for the abovementioned tickets method.

Thank you in advance for your insights!

Now to the code... Let me know if there are other morsels you'd like for me to serve up

**creating_tickets_spec.rb**

Right at the top, as part of the before action, click_link "New Ticket"

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Creating tickets" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "Internet Explorer")

    visit '/'
    click_link "Internet Explorer"
    click_link "New Ticket"
  end

  scenario "Creating a ticket" do
    fill_in "Title", with: "Non-standards compliance"
    fill_in "Description", with: "My pages are ugly!"
    click_button "Create Ticket"

    expect(page).to have_content("Ticket has been created.")
  end

  scenario "Creating a ticket without valid attributes fails" do
    click_button "Create Ticket"

    expect(page).to have_content("Ticket has not been created.")
    expect(page).to have_content("Title can't be blank")
    expect(page).to have_content("Description can't be blank")
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% title(@project.name, "Projects") %>

<h2><%= @project.name %></h2>

<%= link_to "Edit Project", edit_project_path(@project) %>

<%= link_to "Delete Project",
    project_path(@project),
    method: :delete, # This is intentionally listed as delete rather than the
    # standard destroy method of CRUD.
    data: { confirm:
              "Are you sure you want to delete this project?"
          } %>

<%= link_to "New Ticket", new_project_ticket_path(@project) %>

<!-- This is something I added on my own -->
</br>
<%= link_to "Home", projects_path %>
```

**tickets.controller.rb**

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_project

  def new
    @ticket = @project.tickets.build
  end

  private
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :tickets
end
```

**Gemfile**

Note that I've added a few additional gems outside of those recommended by the text

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.14"

end
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.1'
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "projects#index"

  resources :projects do
    resources :tickets    
  end
end
```

**Terminal output for bin/rake routes**

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 58481
             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                      Controller#Action
               root GET    /                                                projects#index
    project_tickets GET    /projects/:project_id/tickets(.:format)          tickets#index
                    POST   /projects/:project_id/tickets(.:format)          tickets#create
 new_project_ticket GET    /projects/:project_id/tickets/new(.:format)      tickets#new
edit_project_ticket GET    /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id/edit(.:format) tickets#edit
     project_ticket GET    /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#show
                    PATCH  /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#update
                    PUT    /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#update
                    DELETE /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#destroy
           projects GET    /projects(.:format)                              projects#index
                    POST   /projects(.:format)                              projects#create
        new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                          projects#new
       edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                     projects#edit
            project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                          projects#show
                    PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                          projects#update
                    PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                          projects#update
                    DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                          projects#destroy
```

**rspec return**

```
FF

Failures:

  1) Creating tickets Creating a ticket
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Title", with: "Non-standards compliance"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Title"
     # ./spec/features/creating_tickets_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Creating tickets Creating a ticket without valid attributes fails
     Failure/Error: click_button "Create Ticket"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find button "Create Ticket"
     # ./spec/features/creating_tickets_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.24689 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/creating_tickets_spec.rb:12 # Creating tickets Creating a ticket
rspec ./spec/features/creating_tickets_spec.rb:20 # Creating tickets Creating a ticket without valid attributes fails

Randomized with seed 33653
```

Comment: Can you post the source for tickets/new.html.erb?

Comment: At this stage, there is no view file in place. That comes in the next section 5.1.4. 

Looking ahead, it will be a form partial with the expected title and description fields, along with a submit button.

Comment: Got it.   So what's happening is that your test is expecting there to be a form  present after "New Ticket" is clicked.   But since that view hasn't been created yet, Rails is probably throwing up an error page instead.   That's why it is unable to find the fields / buttons you're expecting.

Comment: ^^^^ Big EFFING guess.   You can verify this by switching your capybara driver to selenium (you'll need to install the selenium-driver gem" and watching the test execute in the browser.

Comment: Cool I follow you, thank you Josh!

The only thing I can think of is that the text seems to be thinking the spec will return the error messages that are shown in the console... Because as you and Taryn are saying, Failures for those returns were never coded in. I doubt the authors think that, they're reputable, so it's probably best to just chalk it up as a fluke and move on.  As long as I'm confused by the text for the right reasons, then I'm happy to move on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected something was inconsistent on my end, so I continued to research my problem further. It turns out the reason I was not seeing the same error messages returned by rspec as mentioned in the text is because I installed the excellent better_errors gem into a :development and :test group.

Evidently, when running this gem in :test, it hijacks the error output before it has a chance to cycle through to rspec+capybara. Once I moved the gem to only be part of the :development group, the test results became consistent with both the reference text and with what I assume Taryn and Josh thought I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to begin with, you are getting the correct error for the code you have.

Walk through the test in the browser to see what actually happens... you visit the link, click "Internet explorer", then click the button "New ticket".

There *is* a button called that, so the spec does not fail when you do that.

The browser will correctly take you to a standard Rails failure page.

rspec+capybara have no problem with this happening - it isn't an exception in the spec... you do have to actually test real error pages in capybara - so they are not counted as a problem for the spec.

Think of it this way - if I were a self-aware instance of capybara, I'd be thinking "right, and next we're going to test that we correctly display the error page" ;)

The reason you're failing on the title is of course that error page does not have a form with a field called title...

So... just go ahead and implement the new ticket method and carry on :)

Comment: This answer is vague and I don't think it does a great job at addressing the problem stated in the question.   So I downvoted it.   If however, @spectator6 indicates he finds this answer helpful, I'll reverse the vote.

Comment: @Taryn East - Interesting, I didn't know that about spec! Great explanation! I am confused on one point though... That being the case, what would cause spec to return the error message that the text is expecting? Failure/Error: click_link "New Ticket" / NoMethodError: / undefined method 'tickets' for yadda yadda

Comment: The second spec is expecting validation errors, which would be caused by submitting an invalid form, which is the case when you click "Create Ticket" without filling anything in.       Make sense?

Comment: @Taryn East - To follow up a bit more, is the issue possibly that I'm confusing what spec should be outputting? Because like you're saying the console does show the request going through, but immediately hits a brick wall due to "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms) / NameError - uninitialized constant Project::Ticket ..."

If I'm reading you correctly, are you saying this error would need to be coded into the spec test in order for it to pop up a Fail before it advances to search for the form fields? #tryingtolearnsomethingnew

Comment: @Josh Deeden - Yes, I think that makes sense. You're saying that essentially, the before action as fulfilled in that it WAS able to do the visit, link, and link. So, that being the case, the first opportunity spec has to fail is on the leading scenario, when it looks to complete form fields.  Is that close?

Comment: @Spectator6 Yeah, the commands in the before hook seem to be running correctly, which is what I would expect based on your code.   If you have not in fact implemented the Ticket Model (should just be `Ticket`, btw.  Not `Project::Ticket`), or the tickets/new view, then you would expect to see an application error in the log.   However, the test will simply report a failure because it can't find what it's looking for (because there's an error page where it's expecting a form)

Comment: I have a follow-up concern...

Is there a way to have spec fail tests if errors are returned? Because the same sort of situation happened again. The new ticket form is rocking and rolling, all the expected fields can be manipulated, and the Create Ticket button exists. So spec passes with flying colors, yet the button is not functional until its associated methods are defined in the controller. The text says it should alert to this Failure, but it doesn't. 

I'm thinking ahead when I'm running a complex site w/out a tutorial to rest on, trying to understand how I could catch these situations.

Comment: Yes you are correct - in order to check that it correctly fails, you'd do something like expect that the page contains a routing error or the no-method error for the controller. Whatever the actual text is for that error page :)

Comment: Also, I think you possibly have a framing error in your understanding: capybara tests the things that the user sees in the browser. It does not test the code, but the expected things a user sees in the UI. If you expect the user to see an error-page when you do X, then in your test you should do X, then have an expectation of the content of the error page. To test that the controller code gives a specific error - you should have a controller test and do X, and then add an expectation that you see the given error.